# Projectivity over subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $R$ be a ring, $S \subseteq R$ a subring, and $M$ is a (left) $R$-module. If $M$ is projective as an $S$ module, then does it follow that $M$ is projective as an $R$-module?

I guess yes, since $S$-projectivity of $M$ is equivalent to the existence of an embedding
$$
M \hookrightarrow S^{\oplus k}
$$
for some $k$. But since $S^{\oplus k}$ clearly embeds into $R^{\oplus k}$, we "must" also have $R$-projectivity. But maybe I have done something very stupid . . .

Comment: You confuse "embedding" with "being direct summand of".

Comment: $M=S$ already gives lots of counterexamples by the way. As general hint: before trying to prove something for projective modules, try to prove it for free modules. And before that, try to prove it for the free module of rank 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S=K$ a field, $R=K[x]$ and $M=K[x]/(x^2)$.